# Parsing Nested XML Data in Python Using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

### Updates: Towards a Solution

This code:

```
tree = ET.parse(assetsfilename)
root = tree.getroot()
assets = {}

def find_rows(rowset, container):
    for row in rowset.findall("row"):
        singleton = int((row.get('singleton')))
        flag = int((row.get('flag')))
        quantity = int((row.get('quantity')))
        typeID = int((row.get('typeID')))
        locationID = int((row.get('locationID', '0')))
        itemID = int((row.get('itemID')))
        dkey = (singleton, flag, quantity, typeID, locationID, itemID)

        container[dkey] = {}
        child_rowset = row.find("rowset")
        if child_rowset is not None:
            find_rows(child_rowset, container[dkey])

first_rowset = root.find('.//rowset[@name="assets"]')
find_rows(first_rowset, assets)
#print singleton, flag, quantity, typeID, locationID, itemID
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(assets)
```

Gives this output:

```
{   (0, 4, 1, 3317, 61000419, 1000913922710L): {   },
    (0, 4, 1, 6159, 60003463, 1007025519384L): {   },
    (0, 4, 1, 7669, 60000361, 1007215573625L): {   },
    (0, 4, 1, 23566, 61000419, 1000992661686L): {   },
    (1, 4, 1, 51, 60001345, 1004073218074L): {   },
    (1, 4, 1, 51, 60001345, 1004073218075L): {   },
    (1, 4, 1, 596, 60003337, 1007908184113L): {   (0, 5, 1, 34, 0, 1007908184132
L): {   },
                                                  (1, 27, 1, 3634, 0, 1007908184
129L): {   },
                                                  (1, 28, 1, 3651, 0, 1007908184
130L): {   }},
    (1, 4, 1, 3766, 61000419, 1000973178550L): {   (0, 5, 25, 16273, 0, 10009731
88870L): {   },
                                                   (1, 27, 1, 21096, 0, 10006872
93796L): {   }}}
```

This basically adds a nested dict to the end of the dict I already had and fills it with the data from the children, if present.  Ideally, though, both the parent and the children data would be in the main dict and the extra field at the end of the dict would contain the itemID of the parent (if that row is a child row) or be empty (if that item is a parent row or a row that doesn't have any children.)

### The Question

I am trying to read in the data from a nested .xml file into some sort of dictionary so that I can output it in other formats (my current goal is sqlite3 and an sqlite .db file, but this isn't the point of my question.)  I can read all of the primary level of the data but I can't figure out how to also read in the nested data (if present.)

### The Data

Here is a sample .xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2012-11-14 03:26:35</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="assets" key="itemID" columns="itemID,locationID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
      <row itemID="1007215573625" locationID="60000361" typeID="7669" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="0" />
      <row itemID="1004073218074" locationID="60001345" typeID="51" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1" />
      <row itemID="1004073218075" locationID="60001345" typeID="51" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1" />
      <row itemID="1007908184113" locationID="60003337" typeID="596" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1">
        <rowset name="contents" key="itemID" columns="itemID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
          <row itemID="1007908184129" typeID="3634" quantity="1" flag="27" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1" />
          <row itemID="1007908184130" typeID="3651" quantity="1" flag="28" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1" />
          <row itemID="1007908184132" typeID="34" quantity="1" flag="5" singleton="0" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
      <row itemID="1007025519384" locationID="60003463" typeID="6159" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="0" />
      <row itemID="1000913922710" locationID="61000419" typeID="3317" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="0" />
      <row itemID="1000973178550" locationID="61000419" typeID="3766" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1">
        <rowset name="contents" key="itemID" columns="itemID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
          <row itemID="1000687293796" typeID="21096" quantity="1" flag="27" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1" />
          <row itemID="1000973188870" typeID="16273" quantity="25" flag="5" singleton="0" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
      <row itemID="1000992661686" locationID="61000419" typeID="23566" quantity="1" flag="4" singleton="0" />
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2012-11-14 07:05:29</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

Note how some items have children items nested under them but some don't and the number of children (if present) is not fixed (so one item can have 3 children and another 2 children while many others have no children at all.)

(For those curious, this data comes from the full id key Asset List API pull from the online game called EVE Online.)

### What I Can Get

I can get this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(assetsfilename)
root = tree.getroot()

singleton = []
flag = []
quantity = []
typeID = []
locationID = []
itemID = []
assets = {}
for row in root.findall(".//*[@name='assets']/row"):
    singleton.append (int((row.get('singleton'))))
    flag.append (int((row.get('flag'))))
    quantity.append (int((row.get('quantity'))))
    typeID.append (int((row.get('typeID'))))
    locationID.append (int((row.get('locationID'))))
    itemID.append (int((row.get('itemID'))))
assets = zip(singleton, flag, quantity, typeID, locationID, itemID)
print singleton, flag, quantity, typeID, locationID, itemID
print assets
```

To output this on the screen:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0] [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [7669
, 51, 51, 596, 6159, 3317, 3766, 23566] [60000361, 60001345, 60001345, 60003337,
 60003463, 61000419, 61000419, 61000419] [1007215573625L, 1004073218074L, 100407
3218075L, 1007908184113L, 1007025519384L, 1000913922710L, 1000973178550L, 100099
2661686L]
[(0, 4, 1, 7669, 60000361, 1007215573625L), (1, 4, 1, 51, 60001345, 100407321807
4L), (1, 4, 1, 51, 60001345, 1004073218075L), (1, 4, 1, 596, 60003337, 100790818
4113L), (0, 4, 1, 6159, 60003463, 1007025519384L), (0, 4, 1, 3317, 61000419, 100
0913922710L), (1, 4, 1, 3766, 61000419, 1000973178550L), (0, 4, 1, 23566, 610004
19, 1000992661686L)]
```

Note how this is reading in all the main level lines that start `<row itemID=` but it doesn't get the nested lines (which I would preferably like to also show somehow as being tied to the parent itemID above it.)

### Desired Output

I'm somewhat open to suggestions here, but this is one option.  I could have the main level rows parsed into a dict (as I already have) and then create another dict that contains the data from the sublevel rows and adds in an extra piece that notes which itemID it is a child of.  Another option would be to add the data from the sub-level rows into the main dict that I can already make and just add in an extra field the is something like `Null` or `None` for items that don't have a parent and gives the parent's itemID for items that do have a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet (somewhat larger) recursively parses the xml structure into nested dictionaries, like you described a possible solution. It works with the sample you provided, but I think it will work with live data anyway. If nothing else, you can use the idea.

**UPDATE:** Ok, this updated version stores itemID as key, and adds parent_id as additional dict attribute, check it out if that's the desired behavior:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from StringIO import StringIO
tree = ET.parse(StringIO(xml_data))
root = tree.getroot()

assets = {}

def find_rows(rowset, parent_id):
    for row in rowset.findall("row"):
        singleton = int((row.get('singleton')))
        flag = int((row.get('flag')))
        quantity = int((row.get('quantity')))
        typeID = int((row.get('typeID')))
        locationID = int((row.get('locationID', '0')))
        itemID = int((row.get('itemID')))

        assets[itemID] = {'singleton': singleton,
                          'flag': flag,
                          'quantity': quantity,
                          'typeID': typeID,
                          'locationID': locationID,
                          'parentID': parent_id}
        child_rowset = row.find("rowset")
        if child_rowset is not None:
            find_rows(child_rowset, itemID)

first_rowset = root.find('.//rowset[@name="assets"]')
find_rows(first_rowset, None)
```

Comment: I've updated my question post with a section at the top for attemped solutions.  This does work as you say it does, but I was hoping to have the extra field in my dictionary be the itemID for the parent if present rather than adding in a dict with all the children if present.
The `if child_rowset:` line gives a warning `FutureWarning: The
 behavior of this method will change in future versions.  Use specific 'len(elem
)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.`  I changed that line to `if child_rowset is not None:` and it still works and doesn't give this warning.